# Spring/JPA Multithreading Deadlock

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jpa, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot app with dependency on `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. I have a simple repository like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<FooEntity, Integer> {
}
```

And I have a simple controller like this:

```
@RestController
public class FooController {
    private FooRepository fooRepo;

    public FooController(final FooRepository fooRepo) {
        this.fooRepo = fooRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "{id}}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<FooEntity> getFoo(@PathVariable("id") int fooId) {
        FooEntity ent = fooRepo.findOne(fooId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ent, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

But my application is constantly running into deadlock issues. Even with 10 users trying to fetch Foo at the same time results in the error:

```
Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

What's the best method to make all database transactions in the application thread safe?

**Edit 1:** This not only occurs with gets but also saves and updates. One solution to the issue is adding the Java keyword `synchronized` to the repository method. This fixes all the deadlock issues and no more worries. But does that mean we would have to add that keyword to every single repo method? Is there a more sustainable solution?

Comment: A simple select like that shouldn't cause any transaction problems. Which database are you using? Have you looked at the database to see what kind of queries are being performed and what kind of locks taken?

Comment: @Kayaman sql server. It's not just select statements, while that is causing issues also the save/update calls are too

Comment: Well that makes more sense. It wouldn't be possible to get deadlocks with just the code you showed. So, welcome to the world of database programming. Thread safety has nothing to do with this and there's no magic bullet that would fix all your problems. I recommend doing a lot of reading.

Comment: Did you specify any connection pool properties in application.properties and also is it WAR or JAR and JNDI?

Comment: @Kayaman reading what exactly? I am fine with researching but just want to know what I should be looking for and reading about

Comment: Generally about databases and transaction isolation first, then read about JPA to see how it works on top of the database. Then you'll know more than the average Joe who just copies syntax blindly and has no idea what actually happens underneath.

Comment: Maybe this article can clarify something about reads and locks in jpa. https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/

Answer (score 0):

As Kayaman said, this should be because of a write or update operation, but no much more can be said with the data you provide. My guess is that a transaction is timing out while waiting another transaction to end, so it assumes deadlock. Have a look at SQL Queries log and see what is executing, and what is waiting in the moment of deadlock, perhaps this could give you some hint.